# Software sharing for installation

Tags: network-share, file-sharing

I have a couple of software that I want to share over the network locally and hopefully through the internet. The thing is, I only want to share it so that people could install these software through the network from my PC or Server but not necessarily letting them copy or download the installer file into their devices. Could anyone point me into the right direction please?

Answer (score 2):

No sir, not at all.

To a computer, there is no difference between "read the file to execute it" or "read the file to install it", and "read the file to copy it." If you controlled the other workstations, you could implement something in policy that might achieve your goals, but it doesn't sound like that's your situation.

Comment: As mfinni said this is not something you can do in the way you are asking. You could (for instance) set up a website to run the software...on your PC. But to let them install it **is** to let them copy it. Lots of vendors have solutions for this sort of thing in the enterprise but they pretty much all require you to have administrative rights to the workstations.